# Load html content in div

Tags: jquery, html, load, jquery-load

I am trying to load the content from another html file into my existing html file using jquery `.load`

But unfortunately it is not loading the content.

Please suggest me with the proper solution.

Here is my existing html and jquery to load content from external HTML file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Review</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <ul class="reviews" id="revw">

            </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
    function check(){
$( "#revw" ).load( "review_list.html #test" );
}
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Page from which we need to load the content

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id='test'>
 Load this content to the id="revw" div.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are not calling the function `check()` anywhere..

Answer (score 3):

You are not calling the function `check()` anywhere.

Try this:

```
...
<script>
function check() {
    $( "#revw" ).load('review_list.html #target');
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    check(); // call the function
});
</script>
...
```

Comment: I tried this but not working.. `$(document).ready(function() {
    check(); 
    $( "#revw" ).load( "review_list.html #test" );
});`

Comment: I am doing this in local and plain html files

Comment: I believe this will help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: @techfoobar And is it possible to path to the html file like this: foldername/review_list.html ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this using `$.get`.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('review_list.html')
             .success(function(data) {
                 $('#revw').html(data);
             });
    });
```

Your HTML page

```
<div id='test'>
 Load this content to the id="revw" div.
</div>
```

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/V_2/review_list.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. ` I am getting this error when i see in the inspect element cosole (chrome). Content is not loading

Comment: You cannot load or post or get without a web server. Only plain html files works for you (i.e) No xmlHttpRequest will work without a web server.

Comment: I am using plain html file only. I have only these 2files in my folder but y it is not loading the content? Do I need to upload files to server to get the result?

Comment: Yes, you need to upload it to the server to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer this link :

[Load one page in to another using Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424477/loading-one-html-page-inside-other-using-jquery)

It has a detailed explaination of your problem

[Delayed loading of a html page using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966879/using-jquery-to-load-one-html-file-delay-then-another-looping)

Both these will solve the probelm.